# PHP Globals variable

Tags: php, global-variables

I know that global variables are not advisable to use but in my case I don't have another alternative. I would like to store some data in global variables for later use in the same script. Here is my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['details_submit'])){
    $body = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);

    $GLOBALS['details'] = "";
    foreach ($body as $key => $value) {
        $details.= "Item : ".$value['item_name'];
        $details.= ", Quantity : ".$value['quantity'];
        $details.= ", Amount : ".$value['amount'];
        $details.= ", Total : ".$value['total']."\n";
    }
    echo $details;

    $GLOBALS['subtotal'] = 0;
    foreach ($body as $key => $value) {
        $subtotal = $value['total'] + $subtotal;
    }
    echo $subtotal;
}// end if statement

if(isset($_POST['customer_submit'])){
    $customer = "";
    $customer.= "Customer : ".$_POST['Name']."\n";
    $customer.= "Email : ".$_POST['Email']."\n";
    $customer.= "Phone Number : ".$_POST['Phone']."\n";
    $customer.= "Residence : ".$_POST['Area'];
    echo $customer;

    $email = $_POST['Email'];

    $to    = 'example@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Natures Touch Order';
    $message = "<b>Customer Order</b> \n"
                   .$details."\n
                <b>Customer Details</b> \n"
                   .$customer."\n
                 The subtotal is KSH ".$subtotal.".";

    $headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n";
          'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $send1 = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
?>
```

The global variables are `details` and `subtotal` as shown in my code. The reason I am using global variables is because I have two different `if` statements and would like to use some of the results in the first `if` statement in the second `if` statement. Everything works well but when it comes to sending the mail i get `Undefined variable details and subtotal` error. Could it be that the data is not being stored in the variables when the first if statement is run?? Or what could be the problem??

Comment: Side note `$headers` needs concatenation, not semicolon. The `'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion()` is not included in your header as you have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a variable at the start of your code

```
<?php
    $a = 0;
?>
```

and assign a value, then change the value if and when it is needed further on in your code.

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php